# Height auto is not working in left side menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image]

I am developing a website in which a am facing height auto problem .here is my [website link](http://justus-new.bluecoresys.com/UserHome.php) ,where you can see the problem on left side menu when i click on "Dentists" category the sliding menu goes down but page height is not increasing auto as well.i kept height auto of my page still its not working.
if anyone have this solution then let me know as soon as possible ?

Here is my code which i am using for it :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
                    $('#accordion-1').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'click',
                        autoClose: true,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        speed: 'slow',
                        showCount: true,
                        autoExpand: true,
                        cookie  : 'dcjq-accordion-1',
                        classExpand  : 'dcjq-current-parent'
                    });
                    $('#accordion-2').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'click',
                        autoClose: false,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        speed: 'fast',
                        classActive: 'test',
                        showCount: true
                    });
                    $('#accordion-3').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'click',
                        autoClose: false,
                        saveState: false,
                        disableLink: false,
                        showCount: false,
                        speed: 'slow'
                    });
                    $('#accordion-4').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: true,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        menuClose: false,
                        speed: 'slow',
                        showCount: true
                    });
                    $('#accordion-5').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: false,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        menuClose: true,
                        speed: 'fast',
                        showCount: true
                    });
                    $('#accordion-6').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: false,
                        saveState: false,
                        disableLink: false,
                        showCount: false,
                        menuClose: true,
                        speed: 'slow'
                    });
});
</script>
<link href="css/skins/graphite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php 
/****code for category list in feft menu*******/

$default = array('table' => 'category',
                            'fields' => '*',
                            'order' => 'CategoryId',
                            'sort' => 'ASC',
                            'limit' => "999999");
$arryfirst=$CommonObj->select($default);

?>
<div id="whole_category1">
        <div class="graphite demo-container">
<ul class="accordion" id="accordion-1">
         <?php if(!empty($arryfirst))
 { 
 foreach($arryfirst as $row1)
 {
         $catid = $row1['category']['CategoryId'];
         $actname = $row1['category']['Category'];    


     ?>

         <li><a href="ProductHome.php?catid=<?php echo $catid; ?>"><?php echo  $actname ; ?></a>    
         <ul> 
         <?php $default2 = array('table' => 'subcategory',
                            'fields' => '*',
                            'condition' => "CategoryId='$catid'",
                            'order' => 'CategoryId',

                            'limit' => "999999");
$arry2=$CommonObj->select($default2);
     if(!empty($arry2))
 { 
 foreach($arry2 as $row2)
 {  
         $sbcatid = $row2['subcategory']['SubCategoryId'];
         $sbctname = $row2['subcategory']['SubCategoryName'];    

    ?>
    <li ><a style="padding-bottom: 6px;padding-top: 5px;" href="ProductHome.php?sbcatid=<?php echo $sbcatid; ?>"> <?php echo $sbctname; ?></a></li>
   <?php } } ?>

</ul></li>

             <?php  }
 } ?>
</ul>


</div>
        <!-- <div class="sidebg2"></div>--> 
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove height attribute from .demo-container

Comment: if i do this then right side content is not working properly . i want all the right side content at same place when i click on any category.

Comment: remove <br>s and <div class="clear"></div> also remove margin-top from  .left5

Comment: you should also use the developer tools provided in chrome and firefox browsers, it makes your life a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

http://justus-new.bluecoresys.com/css/dcaccordion.css

in line 6 you define height:700px

you should get delete of that

Answer (score 0):

just remove the height in .demo-container

.demo-container  {
  height: 700px; // remove this
}